# Split data from excel based on data value using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe in below format

```
version,1.3.0
info,team,Australia
info,team,India
info,gender,male
ball,1,0.5,India,V Sehwag,IK Pathan,B Lee,0,0,"",""
ball,1,0.6,India,V Sehwag,IK Pathan,B Lee,0,0,"",""
```

I want to split data into two using pandas

First dataframe

```
info,team,Australia
info,team,India
info,gender,male
```

Second dataframe

```
ball,1,0.5,India,V Sehwag,IK Pathan,B Lee,0,0,"",""
ball,1,0.6,India,V Sehwag,IK Pathan,B Lee,0,0,"",""
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a dataframe

Comment: (df = pd.read_csv('merge_data/291353.csv', sep='delimit',header=None)

Comment: @AmarShah - So it is not excel file? Separator is not comma? Maybe need `df = pd.read_csv('merge_data/291353.csv', header=None, skiprows=1)`

Comment: Skiprows removed the version line, but i want to keep lines having 'info' in one data frame and second dataframe containing 'balls'

Comment: @AmarShah - So first line is not `version,1.3.0` ?

Comment: Yes...first line is version,1.3.0

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools` `groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

text = """version,1.3.0
info,team,Australia
info,team,India
info,gender,male
ball,1,0.5,India,V Sehwag,IK Pathan,B Lee,0,0,"",""
ball,1,0.6,India,V Sehwag,IK Pathan,B Lee,0,0,"",""
"""

g = groupby(text.splitlines()[1:], key=lambda x: x.split(',')[0])

df1, df2 = (
    pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO('\n'.join(t[1])), header=None)
    for t in g
)

print(df1, df2, sep='\n\n')

      0       1          2
0  info    team  Australia
1  info    team      India
2  info  gender       male

     0   1    2      3         4          5      6   7   8   9   10
0  ball   1  0.5  India  V Sehwag  IK Pathan  B Lee   0   0 NaN NaN
1  ball   1  0.6  India  V Sehwag  IK Pathan  B Lee   0   0 NaN NaN
```

Comment: It is excel file.

Comment: How can i achieve this using CSV files, which i am reading and its coming as dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I believe need:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, header=None, skiprows=1)

df1 = df[df[0] == 'info']
df2 = df[df[0] == 'ball']
```

Or more general is create `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(0)))

print (dfs['info'])
print (dfs['ball'])
```

EDIT: If there is multiple files and is better use `csv` module with append each line to list by first value and then create `DataFrame`s by contructor:

```
import csv, glob

info, ball = [],[]
for f in glob.glob('csv/*.csv'):
    with open(f, "r") as f1:
        reader = csv.reader(f1)
        for L in reader:
            if L[0] == 'info':
                info.append(L)
            if L[0] == 'ball':
                ball.append(L)

#print (info)
#print (ball)           

df1 = pd.DataFrame(info)
print (df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(ball)
print (df2)
```

---

If want create for each file 2 DataFrames:

```
for f in glob.glob('csv/*.csv'):
    with open(f, "r") as f1:
        info, ball = [],[]
        reader = csv.reader(f1)
        for L in reader:
            if L[0] == 'info':
                info.append(L)
            if L[0] == 'ball':
                ball.append(L)

        df1 = pd.DataFrame(info)
        print (df1)

        df2 = pd.DataFrame(ball)
        print (df2)
```

Another solution:

```
for f in glob.glob('csv/*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='delimit',
                     skipinitialspace = True,
                     skiprows=1,
                     quotechar = '"',
                     names=['data'])
    df1 = df.loc[df['data'].str.startswith('info'), 'data'].str.split(',',expand=True)
    df2 = df.loc[df['data'].str.startswith('ball'), 'data'].str.split(',',expand=True)
    print (df1)
    print (df2)
```

Comment: @AmarShah - There is some error ? Can you explain more?

Comment: df = pd.read_excel(file, header=None, skiprows=1)

df1 = df[df[0] == 'info']

This is returning all the rows even with data having 'balls'

Comment: @AmarShah - What is `print (df[0].tolist())` ?

Comment: @AmarShah - Are data confidental?

Comment: No...do you want me to share the CSV file?

Comment: @AmarShah - Yes you can share your data in gdocs, dropbox or send it to my email from my profile.

Comment: Sent you via email

Comment: @AmarShah - There is multiple csv files with similar format?

Comment: @AmarShah - And output is 2 csv big files, one for `info` and one for `file` with joindex 200 files\?

Comment: @AmarShah - OK, is possible send me more files?

Comment: Send you more files.

Comment: I found one way to separate data

matchData = df[df[0].str.match('info')]
runsData = df[df[0].str.match('ball')]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to split the data. Code is as below.
I am reading 200 CSV files and converting into 2 dataframes, one with 'info' and other with 'ball'

```
import pandas as pd
import os
files = os.listdir("merge_data")

finalRunsData = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    #Dataframe declaration
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    matchData = pd.DataFrame()
    runsData = pd.DataFrame()
    #Read excel data
    df = pd.read_csv('merge_data/'+file,sep='delimit',header=None,skipinitialspace = True,skiprows=1,quotechar = '"')
    #Split runs data
    matchData = df[df[0].str.match('info')]
    runsData = df[df[0].str.match('ball')]
    #For runs
    finalRunsData = finalRunsData.append(runsData[0].str.split(',',expand=True))
```

Comment: I try a bit imrove your solution in my answer ;)